# "Show Desktop" button on secondary monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar, shortcuts

I have a multi-monitor setup, and the "show desktop" button is at the end of the taskbar on the primary monitor. This is now a problem since I have to awkwardly position my mouse in the middle of both screens to make use of it. Is there anyway to get this button at the end of the taskbar on either both monitors or only the second monitor?

Here is a screenshot for those that are confused:

[image: Show Desktop Button]

Note: **I am not looking for solutions that create a shortcut/link to the desktop which is *not* at the very end of the taskbar. That defeats the whole point, since then I'll have to navigate to the icon, instead of just moving my mouse to position the pointer at the bottom right of the screen and clicking.**

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately, it's not. See the note in the question. It _must_ be at the end of the taskbar on the second monitor. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, I'm apparently missing something. I believe the answer I gave below will do what you are asking... but it seems you don't agree. Could you expand on why? Perhaps I can offer a better solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, by moving your primary taskbar to the second screen.

1. right-click the main taskbar
2. uncheck where it says `lock all taskbars`
3. click and hold on a blank space in that taskbar and drag it to the other screen
4. make sure other taskbars are possitioned on their screens as you want them.
5. right-click the main taskbar
6. check where it says `lock all taskbars`
7. log out and back in (or restart windows) to ensure the changes are saved.

Personally I only keep a single taskbar on my right monitor (I have three).

Comment: Is there a way to have both taskbars with "Show desktop" and not only a change if it's the right or left one?

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to make it easier to hit that small area at the bottom right corner of your display with your mouse:

Go to display settings and drag your the monitor which is to the right of your primary display to a position sightly *higher* than your primary display. This will have the effect of making a corner where your mouse will get "stuck" in the bottom right corner of the primary display.

Now when you drag your mouse down to the bottom right corner of your main display it won't be able to skip past the Show Desktop button. However, if you do wish to move right to the next display, simply move your mouse up a few pixels and you'll be able to move to the next display.

Comment: Ingenious!12345

Comment: Awesome tip! solved my problem! Thanks!!

Comment: Nice. Not bad. Unfortunately it does mean you can no longer cross from the top of the right monitor to the left monitor without also dodging downwards. But possibly worth being able to use Peek again. Will try it out...

Comment: Well, why not. My monitors don't have the same dpi anyway, so it's not like they'll ever line up (laptop + extra monitor)

Answer (score 1):

You could change what your primary display is. In a setup with a task bar per screen (as I run it) - in the windows 10 display settings page, pick the screen

[image]

[image]

The main display will *always* have the task bar hot-area for showing the main screen. So.. set your *second*/right screen as the primary and you'd get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, hotkey <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> minimizes all windows on all displays to show the desktop.

You can use [MaxTo](https://maxto.net/) to create a custom hotkey for showing desktop **only on the currently active** display. I bound mine to <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Here is the recipe you can import as a MaxTo recipe.

```json
{
  "enabled": true,
  "name": "Show desktop on current monitor",
  "id": null,
  "triggers": [
    {
      "type": "keyboard:hotkey",
      "Hotkey": "Shift+Windows+D"
    }
  ],
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "command": "window:minimize",
      "parameters": {
        "window": "\\*\\*\\*",
        "monitor": "$current",
        "all": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```